# Auto Growing Div in other Auto Growing Div with dynamic floating content

Tags: html, css

Got a small tricky issue :/ I've got an absolute positioned div with NO width as the content is created dynamically.

In this div there is another absolute positioned div, again with no width as the content is created dynamically.

In this div there are two floating divs with dynamically created content so they can't have width either.

My problem now is that they don't want to stay in ONE LINE. Instead it looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dHQm/2/

```
 <div style="left: 100px; top: 200px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid green;">

        This is the main container<br />
        Here is some dynamically created content ...<br />
        ...<br />
        ...<br />
        ...<br />
        ...<br />
        ...<br />
        ...<br />

             <div id="test" style="left: 100px; top: 50px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid red;">

                <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid yellow; margin: 10px">
                    dynamically created content (float left)
                </div>

                <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid blue; margin: 10px">
                    dynamically created content (float left)
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

But it should look like this where I added a static width, which I can't do live as the content is dynamic:

http://jsfiddle.net/EGfhy/

```
<div id="test" style="left: 100px; top: 50px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid red; width: 550px">
```

In addition I can't change the position:absolute in any circumstance :/ I've been trying things for ages now. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot :)

JB

Comment: The key issue here is that your markup implies a relationship between the child div and the parent div- the child div's ("test") dimensions are completely dependent on the parent div. If "test" is meant to have it's own set of dimensions, unrelated to the parent except for general positioning, I recommend wrapping BOTH divs in a container and positioning them according to that parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with some use of `display:inline-block`, if you don't mind abandoning your usage of floats.

I removed the `float:left` from your two `<div>` elements inside `#test`, and then added this CSS:

```
#test {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#test > div {
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline; /* For inline-block support in IE7 */
}
```

Inline-blocks will naturally line up next to each other. the `white-space:nowrap` ensures that the inline blocks (and actually the text inside them too) will stay next to each other even if the parent isn't naturally wide enough - and will expand the parent accordingly (if possible, otherwise it'll just extend out of the parent).

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dHQm/5/) that shows what this achieves, which I think looks pretty much like your "working but set-width" JSFiddle. I hope this is what you're looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: YES! How nice! This is exactly i was looking for! I just added an vertical-align: top; so that the content wont go down to the bottom in case one container grows bigger.          
    
I noticed that in some browsers like IE 10 it causes layout problems if i use normal floats IN an inline-block element especially with margins... I dont know why this happens :/ maybe someone does?  
  
So be careful :) and big thanks again !

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you out. Oh uh...if this did answer your question though, could you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure this won't be a problem, but just be aware that inline-block is only supported on IE 8 and above.

Comment: Good point! I'll add the inline-block hack to account for the wonderful intricacies of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force floats to line up unless they have a set width. That's kind of the point of floats. They will "float" depending on the size of the elements. You could try using the min-width property. This would force the element to be at least a certain size. If you set this to the minimum width needed for the elements to line up as you want then it should work whatever the content. Of course, if your elements get too big then the layout might change again so you may well need to set max-width too. I would also suggest using percentages for these values to make things flexible. 
Note that you will need to set these properties on the parent elements too for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts musoNic80 :), still something learned !